# Camera stopped working, how to check if it's hardware problem?

Tags: camera

I'm quite sure this is hardware problem. I tried the following:

- cleared application cache and restarted phone
- tried alternative camera applications
- reset phone to factory settings (still doesn't work)

There is just error message saying:

> Unfortunately, Gallery has stopped.

Now I suspect it could be Gallery app problem. I rooted the phone and used super user app to disable Gallery and than install alternative gallery app. Still not working, now error is

> Camera has stopped working

Is there any way I can check if actual camera is broken? I'm using Android 4.2.2 on the [Doogee DG130](http://www.doogeemobile.com/doogee-dg130-smartphone-android-4-2-card-dual-4-3-inch-5mp-camera.html)?

Log file ( part about camera ): 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0-PZcQ_Q9-ZV1pON0ZlMzNjck0/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the exception stack trace from the logcat

```
08-19 17:03:08.098 W/dalvikvm(18229): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414369a8)
08-19 17:03:08.098 D/IPCThreadState(18229): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x50840260
08-19 17:03:08.100 E/AndroidRuntime(18229): FATAL EXCEPTION: Camera Handler Thread
08-19 17:03:08.100 E/AndroidRuntime(18229): java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
08-19 17:03:08.100 E/AndroidRuntime(18229):     at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
08-19 17:03:08.100 E/AndroidRuntime(18229):     at com.mediatek.camera.AndroidCamera.startPreview(AndroidCamera.java:168)
08-19 17:03:08.100 E/AndroidRuntime(18229):     at com.android.camera.CameraManager$CameraHandler.handleMessage(CameraManager.java:168)
08-19 17:03:08.100 E/AndroidRuntime(18229):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
08-19 17:03:08.100 E/AndroidRuntime(18229):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
08-19 17:03:08.100 E/AndroidRuntime(18229):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

And this is entire log for last 2 minutes ( while I was opening a camera ):
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0-PZcQ_Q9-ZTW9QeTVKdk1NdEU/edit?pli=1

Comment: Provide output of logcat command

Comment: It's probably the Gallery, it is very tightly linked to the camera in stock Android. Try re-enabling it. Alternatively try installing another camera from the market, but NOT a Google one for obvious reasons. See if that works.

Comment: @RossC thanks I will try, I used an app to disable gallery only, I didnt actually remove it completely. When enabled I get gallery error, without it I just get camera error

Comment: Your nuclear option is to flash a new ROM or a backup. But obviously don't do that first. Try re-enabling, rebooting, re-installing apps etc as you go. Try to narrow it down. What is the Gallery error?

Comment: just says `Unfortunately, Gallery has stopped.` I updated log now, there seems to be errors like: `FATAL EXCEPTION: Camera Handler Thread
08-19 17:03:08.100 E/AndroidRuntime(18229): java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed` but I still cant tell what could be the problem

Comment: Are you using the android OS that came with the phone or a custom ROM? have you modified it at all, like root, deleting system apps, etc? Did it work before? Did anything change when it stopped working?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this application to know whether it has Camera/Hardware problem - 
[System Info Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sysinfodroid&hl=en)
It provides whole summary of the device.